# Django: How to show user owned data in Admin forms

Tags: django, django-admin

Following are the models of my app:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, verbose_name='User')
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                 verbose_name='Store name')
    store_address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                           verbose_name='Address line 1')
    store_address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                            verbose_name='Address line 2')
    store_city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                  verbose_name='City')
    store_state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                   verbose_name='State')
    store_zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                      verbose_name='Zip/Pin Code')
    store_country = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                     verbose_name='Country')
    store_phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name='Phone')
    store_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email')
    store_website = models.URLField(verbose_name='Website')


class StoreDepartment(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, verbose_name='Store')
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, 
                                      verbose_name='Department name')
    department_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=False, 
                                              verbose_name='Description')
```

+++++++++

I am using only the dfault Admin provided by django framwork.

I have 2 users, For both users I have created Stores.
But when I try to create StoreDepartment, I see the list of all the stores in the Select box created for "Store" foreign-key field in StoreDepartment model.

How to customize the default form so that user can see only the Stores created by them in the selectbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following **formfield_for_foreignkey** in Model admin and now its working for me. User can see only the stores owned by him.

```
class StoreDepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['department_name', 'store']
    ordering = ['id']

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "store":
            kwargs["queryset"] =Store.objects.filter(store_owner=request.user)

    return super(StoreDepartmentAdmin,self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```